# Ambient Occlusion Dispersing Unevenly

Tags: uv, node-editor, normals, ambient-occlusion

So I'm still pretty new at using the ambient occlusion node (for making edge wear). And I noticed in certain places it was unevenly dispersing the gradient (which is pretty noticible in the end renders... What am i doing wrong?
[image]

This may be attached to the same problem but I'm also noticing that its not detecting the edges on one side, but detecting on another...
[image]

Node Set-up:
[image]

Comment: Are your normals consistent across the model? (Is AO firing inwards on one side, and outwards on the other)

Comment: @RobinBetts Yeah, in face orientation, it all seems to be facing the same direction...